# How can I index HTML documents?

Tags: .net, indexing, full-text-search, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene .NEt to do full-text searching.  Till now I have been indexing PDF docs, but now I have a few webpages that I need to index.  What's the best/easiest way to index HTML documents to add to my Lucene index?  I am using .NET/C#

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on this problem, the best answer I have found to date is using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to get the plain text content out of the HTML.

Answer (score -3):

Google can index your content for you.

Comment: Not only does the asker *specifically* state that they are using Lucene .NET, even if using Google was an option this answer doesn't contain any real information on how to achieve this.